Is there any Marie Curie post doctoral call right now?
This webpage says that the MSCA (Marie Skłodowska-Curie) postdoctoral call for 2025 ended on 11 September, 2024. Moreover, the next call will be open in April 2025. My field is mathematics.
I am curious to know if this is the only option to apply for Marie Curie postdoctoral fellowship. Does it consider proposals for other types of positions throughout the year?

I'm confused. Your title says "Is there a post-doctoral call right now," but you explain there isn't, and then ask about "other types of positions." What is your actual question?

@AzorAhai-him-, I guess EU funds Marie Curie postdoctoral positions. My question was if there are other projects of EU under the banner of Marie Curie that accepts research proposal from some research labs (located in Europe) throughout the year.

No, the only option to apply for a Marie Curie postdoctoral fellowship is to wait until a call for Marie Curie postdoctoral fellowships is opened on the official website for Marie Curie postdoctoral fellowships and then to follow the instructions in that call.

The call for this action is closed.
The next call will open on 9 April 2025.

